# Prove that $T$ is normal if and only if $\|Tv\| = \|T^*v\|$ for all $v$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm going through the proof of the above theorem in Linear Algebra Done Right (3rd ed). It goes as follows:

\begin{align}
T \text{ is normal } &\iff T^*T - TT^* = 0\\
                     &\iff \langle (T^*T - TT^*)v, v \rangle = 0, \text{ for all } v \in V\\
                     &\iff \langle T^*Tv, v \rangle = \langle TT^*v, v \rangle, \text{ for all } v \in V\\
                     &\iff ||Tv||^2 = ||T^*v||^2 , \text{ for all } v \in V\\
\end{align}

Axler then goes on to mention that the second equivalence follows by (7.16) which states that if $T = T^*$ and $\langle Tv, v \rangle$ = $0$ for all $v$, then $T$ = $0$.

Now to my question:

I haven't managed to convince myself the above stated justification for the second equivalence is needed. More specifically, the first equivalence establishes that $T^*T - TT^*$ is the zero map, and therefore maps all $v \in V$ to $0$. Consequently, $(T^*T - TT^*)v = 0$. We also know that $\langle 0, v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$. Hence, the second equivalence follows directly without having to invoke (7.16). In fact, isn't invoking (7.16) in this case not just redundant but purely wrong, since the implication follows only in one direction?

Comment: Your objection would be reasonable if the author wrote $A=0\Longleftrightarrow \langle Av,w\rangle=0\forall v,w$ but here we're restricting ourselves to the case $v=w$, for which you need something more (like self-adjointness).

Comment: You are clearly using the result that $\langle Av,v\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$ implies $A=0$ when $A$ is self adjoint. Actually, if you are working over $\mathbb{C}$ then $\langle Av,v\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$ implies $A=0$ even if $A$ is not self adjoint. Over $\mathbb{R}$ this isn't the case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary.

> *Claim*. $T^*T - TT^* = 0$ if and only if $\langle (T^*T - TT^*)v,v \rangle = 0$ for any $v \in V$.

*Proof*. $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $T^*T - TT^* = 0$. Then, for any $v \in V$,
$$\langle (T^*T - TT^*)v,v \rangle = \langle 0,v \rangle = 0.$$
$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $\langle (T^*T - TT^*)v,v \rangle = 0$ for any $v \in V$. Define $U := T^*T - TT^*$ and note that $U^*=U$. Then $U^*=U$ and $\langle Uv,v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$ implies that $U=0$ thanks to $(7.16)$.